# How to get data between Table and View without relation with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `Entities` that one of them is `Table` and another one is `View` and I want to get result from them. There is no logical relation between these entities.
My Linq query is:

```
        var eduStandard = App.Api.EduStandardService.Instance().Data();
        var eduPost = App.Api.EduStandardPostService.Instance().Data();
        var result=from es in eduStandard
                   join ep in eduPost on es.StandardID equals ep.StandardID
                   join vp in Data() on ep.PostCode equals vp.CAPACITY_CODE
```

but compiler throw error from second `join` and send this error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: Can we see the definitions for the `ep` and `vp`. Is `PostCode` or `CAPACITY_CODE` a nullable type?

Comment: I completed my code

Comment: What types are `PostCode` and `CAPACITY_CODE`? string? Or something else? For the join to work, they need to be of the same time or have an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   foreach (var es in  eduStandard)
   {      
     var vp = from ep in eduPost
              where ep.StandardId == es.StandardId
              select ep;
     var result = from item in vp 
                  where item.CAPACITY_CODE == ep.PostCode
                  select item;
    }
```

we could still use a definition for the vp table.

Comment: Based on the code `eduPost` is a sequence or collection and would not have a `PostCode` property.

Comment: I need it with relation in linq